# salesforce flow: condition for new record, in after-save

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

in this tutorial https://youtu.be/_qLfDe4IGSg?t=3593, by the 00:59:53 time, he says:

> The best way to know if a record is new, is with a filter like "createdDate isChanged == true"

[image: flow entry condition]
[image: same thing, with better resolution]

Some things i dont get here:

1. The condition entry is for when a record is **updated**. Wont this only get new records, so this condition negates the other date condition?
2. if the createdDate is set upon the original record creation, why would that value change after with any update? Instead isnt LastModifiedDate the value to be updated? And wouldnt the required filter be "LastModifiedDate != createdDate"?

Thanks

Comment: What is it that you are specifically trying to do? Why would you use a condition "A record is updated" if you want to run the flow only when the record is created (so a condition "A record is created" is appropriate)?

Comment: that is the question: if the entry contition is set for only updating records, the filter "createdDate isChanged == true" will always be false, and this trigger flow will never run. I'm just trying to understand what he's doing

Comment: Having not looked at the video, I gonna guess that this is for a re-entrant automation scenario; one where an on create automation has itself initiated an update against the same record. Still, if you have some automation you want to ensure happens once on creation, use the "A record is created" condition for the flow (assuming you're using a flow to implement this automation).

Comment: yes, to trigger the flow on creation, of course getting that on the start contition is the one. this filter would only make sense if it was "Created OR Updated". Then that filter could be used in a decision for a diferent action for each. So that configuration makes no sense to me. Thanks

Comment: That final point is true, but IIRC there's now access to the ISNEW function anyway...?